# AFrameVR A-Frame How do I combine teleport controls & thumb controls

Tags: aframe, trackpad

How do I combine teleport controls component with the thumb controls component?

I managed to get thumb controls to trigger some boxes, but how to I combine thumb controls with teleport controls so that pressing up triggers the teleport?

I got thumb controls working here http://typhoon-rule.glitch.me

In the first example the left thumb click will trigger the box entities to animate.

Side question: why is it that the second animation waits for a second click sometimes, while other times all the animations happen at the same time?

So in the next example which you can see at http://silly-diver.glitch.me I tried to combine the thumb controls script and the teleport controls script into a single script “./script.js” and I tried to replace thumbdown with thumbupstart in every instance I found it and of course that didn’t work at all.

At one point I had teleport working, but not with the left click, with any click, and it caused a second controller to appear.

At this point I am writing a new question because I can’t get anything working anymore and I’m totally not knowledgeable enough to solve this on my own today.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/fernandojsg/aframe-teleport-controls#properties

Should be like: `teleport-controls="startEvents: thumbupstart; endEvents: thumbupend"`

Comment: I tried that, it didn’t work. I am seeing a teleport icon when I press anywhere on the trackpad, (testing with Mirage Solo) but I’m not teleporting anywhere. It’s not only being triggered when I press up.

See my latest build at http://secretive-cone.glitch.me

Comment: I’m not 100% sure what I did but I got it working thanks for all your help!